# Can't find the script templates on Apps Script welcome screen

Tags: google-apps-script

Thanks for the help.

I'm starting my way in Apps Script. I was watching some of Google's video tutorials and in their tutorials there are Script Templates in the welcome screen  for Gmail, Calendar etc, but I can't see them on Apps Script.

It will help a lot to get started.

Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: You can find the welcome screen under, **`Help->Welcome Screen`** menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Parag Jadhav stated, templates can be accessed from the Apps Script editor Welcome Screen (which is shown when the editor is first opened or by clicking the **"Help > Welcome screen"** menu item. Selecting a template from the Welcome Screen will create a new project pre-populated with the code you need to get started.

You may follow through this [guide](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-templates).

> Google Apps Script allows developers to extend and manipulate Google Docs, Sheets and Forms. For those just starting with Apps Script, it can be useful to have a template to work from -- a framework that developers can learn from and modify to suit their needs.

To continue learning about how to extend Google Docs, Sheets and Forms with Apps Script, take a look at the following resources:

- [Overview of Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)
- [Guide to Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/)

Comment: Hey guys thanks, Iv tried this stuff, but still i don't have it. I guess because the vid is from 2012 google made up some changes.
thanks again to all hope someone has that templates it looks good :)